# Complex Header in jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to make something like this header in jQuery DataTable?

[image]

Comment: Please specify in your question what you're having a problem with.

Comment: My problem is how to make a header in JQuery DatabTable like the picture I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see the tabs (mainly the html one): https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Applied to your case, http://jsfiddle.net/t4tzwm6c/
(it really is just a matter of html rowspan and colspan)

Snippet:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Operation conducted</th>
      <th colspan="3">Drug evidence seized</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Shabu</th>
      <th>Majijuana</th>
      <th>Others</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```